# SQL Group By Certain Amounts

Tags: sql, algorithm, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have an order table which has the customer id and order amount. I want to join these orders but joined orders cannot exceed a certain amount. An example below:

Let's say the maximum amount is 33 pallets and I have a table like this:

```
Order ID    Client ID   Amount  
1           100001        10    
2           100001        22    
3           100001        13    
4           100001        33    
5           100001        1    
6           100001        5     
7           100001        6
```

The result should be:

```
Order ID    Client ID   Amount  Joined ID   Joined Amount
1            100001       10    100001A         32
2            100001       22    100001A         32
3            100001       13    100001B         13
4            100001       33    100001C         33
5            100001       1     100001D         12
6            100001       5     100001D         12
7            100001       6     100001D         12
```

Here, if we can also come up with a way to ad orders numbered 5,6,7 to joined order 10001B it would be great. But even this solution will be enough.

I have a few ideas on how to solve this but  I couldn't really come up with a working solution. I'll be handling around 2000 Order Ids like this, so also I don't want this to be a slow operation. I'm using SQL Server 2014

Comment: Is the original `Amount` column guaranteed to never be more than 33?

Comment: You're trying to solve a one-dimensional bin packing problem. I would rather do this in code than in the database, but SQL can probably handle it. I haven't researched in depth, but this article looks like a good explanation of some algorithms: http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-bins1

Comment: I don't get the result at all.  Why wouldn't Order ID 5 be combined with 1 and 2?  Or why would the "the result should be" example be sufficient, when it doesn't look fully optimized?

Comment: @ErikE very good question :) the amount can be over 33, however if it's 1 orderline we can give it a joined it and keep it as it is. We will never split an orderline.

Comment: Please state the version of SQL Server you're using (you tagged 'tsql' so I presume it's SQL Server).

Comment: @orhunadam - you originally stated `the maximum amount is 33 pallets`, and now you're saying the amount can be over 33?  Please stop changing the rules, and post exactly what the issue is.  We can't be expected to come up with an answer if the question keeps changing.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I have quite a different take on this--it seems a very legitimate question and the part about a single line being more than 33 was a simple oversight. You seem very hostile to someone who is just doing his best.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Right now, the main purpose is to join the orders in a way to not exceed 33 pallets. Of course, fully optimizing it would be the perfect solution as you said, but I'll be happy even with the partial one :)

Comment: @ErikE - I never said it wasn't legitimate, and there's no hostility intended.  The problem is the question is like playing whack-a-mole.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables as ErikE stated it was an oversight on my part and sorry for missing that, but I still think that is an exception and if you can provide me an answer with maximum of 33 pallets even in terms of orderlines i can still use it. thanks,

Comment: @ErikE SQL Server 2014, I'm adding this information to the question also.

Comment: @Li One of us saw the potential gap in stated requirements and asked for clarity, the other didn't. One of us complained that the requirements changed without, himself, noticing the lack of clarity, and the other wasn't bothered at all. Think on that a bit.

Comment: @BenJaspers very helpful article indeed!, one of these algortihms would work for me but my main problem is to how to implement them efficiently in sql

Comment: Google SQL Knapsack Problem.  It's non trivial and SQL is not the best suited language for solving it.  Export your data, mine a solution, import the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find proposed solution (sql definition) with help of recursive CTE here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/285c16/45

basicaly CTE iterates ordered list (by clientID, orderID) and evaluate if summed amount is not over 33.

i have added next clientID to mock data, to test correct subcount criteria evaluation.

here is query to obtain results:

```
-- prepare numbering for iteration
with orders_nr
as 
(
  select row_number() over(order by clientID, id) as [nr],
     o.*
  from orders o

)

,
-- prepare sum totals
re
as
(
  select  id, amount, amount as amount_total ,o.[nr] as nr,
    clientID
  from orders_nr o
  where o.[nr]=1
  UNION ALL
  select o.id, o.amount, 
    CASE WHEN o.clientID <> r.clientID then o.amount
    ELSE o.amount+ r.amount_total END,
    o.[nr] as nr, o.clientID
  from orders_nr o  join re r
    on (o.[nr]=r.[nr]+1)

) 
,

 -- iterate total - evaluate current criteria (<=33)
 re2 as
 (
   select re.id, re.amount, re.amount_total, 
     re.[nr] as [group], re.[nr], re.clientID
   from re
   where re.[nr]=1

   UNION ALL

   select r.id, r.amount, 
     CASE WHEN r.amount+re2.amount_total >33
       OR r.clientID<>re2.clientID
         then r.amount ELSE re2.amount_total+r.amount END
       as amount_total,
   CASE WHEN r.amount+re2.amount_total >33 
     OR r.clientID<>re2.clientID THEN 
     r.[nr] ELSE re2.[group] END as [group], r.[nr], r.clientID
   from re r join re2
     on (r.[nr]=re2.[nr]+1 )

  )
  , group_total
  AS
  (
    select [group], clientID, max(amount_total) as total
    FROM re2
    group by [group], clientID
  ),


  result
  as
  (
      select 
   r.id,  r.clientID, r.amount, 
    cast(r.clientid as varchar(20))
      +'-'+char(64+cast(
        dense_rank() 
          over( partition by r.clientID 
               order by r.[clientID], r.[group])
       as varchar(3))) as joinedID
    ,     gt.total as joinedAmount
 from re2 as r join group_total gt
  on (r.clientID=gt.clientID AND r.[group]=gt.[group])
    )
    select * from result
```

Answer (score 0):

Not certain if I'm understanding the question correctly, but you might try

```
select [Client ID], [Joined ID], sum([Amount]) as Total_Amount
from [table_name]
group by [Client ID], [Joined ID]
having sum([Amount]) <= 33
```

It leaves off the Order ID, but since it looks to be unique, you can't use it in a group by.

Edit was to add the having clause in the query to say we can't have something that adds up to more than 33.

Comment: I believe they're trying to group orders with different `Joined ID` values so that they get as close to an amount of 33 as possible.  This answer really doesn't address that, although admittedly what they're asking for really isn't SQL's strong suit.

Comment: Hello Derek, I edited the question to be more specific. And Bobby, Your interpretation is correct, however the main aim is not to be close to 33 as possible but not to exceed it when grouping. Of course being close to 33 would be a bonus but I'm not focusing on that.

Comment: I added a "having" clause in the query, essentially a "where" but for aggregate functions.  I'm not certain this does exactly what you need, in that if there are 3 rows with the same [Joined ID] and they add up to 34, they get left off.

Comment: @DerekCate Actually the joined id should be a result of this query. The query should take a look at [Client Id] and attach one Joined Id value. Then it should look the next order for this Client, and if the sum of these 2 orders are smaller than 33 it should give the same joined id to the second order. And it should go like this. until each order is completed for that client Id

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve with simple selects and without using an explicit cursor but it was a little hard in that way.
I've solved it and got exactly what you wanted with:
a `TempTable`, a `cursor`, a `counter` for checking the sum of sequent amounts, `CHAR()` function to generate letters; I calculated the values and inserted into temp table finally updated the temp table, following is what I tried and the [**DEMO IS HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b96ce/2).

```
create table #tbl_name
       (OrderID int, 
        ClientID int,
        Amount int, 
        joinedId varchar(15) ,
        joinedAmount int)

insert #tbl_name(OrderID,ClientID,Amount) 
select OrderID,ClientID,Amount from tbl_name

declare cr cursor for  
           select orderId, 
             clientId, 
             amount  
           from tbl_name 
           order by OrderId

declare @summedAmount int, 
        @orderId int,
        @clientId int,
        @amount int,
        @counter int

set @summedAmount=0
set @counter=65


open cr
fetch from cr into @orderId,@clientId,@amount
while (@@fetch_status=0)
begin
        if (@amount + @summedAmount < 33)
        begin
            set @summedAmount=@summedAmount+@amount
            update #tbl_name 
            set    joinedId=cast(@ClientId as varchar(10))+char(@counter),
                   joinedAmount=@summedAmount
            where  orderId=@orderId
        end
        else if (@amount + @summedAmount >33)
        begin
            set @counter=@counter+1
            set @summedAmount=@amount
            update #tbl_name 
            set    joinedId=cast(@ClientId as varchar(10))+char(@counter),
                   joinedAmount=@Amount
            where  orderId=@orderId
        end
        fetch from cr into @orderId,@clientId,@amount
end
close cr
deallocate cr
go

with CTE as
(
    select JoinedId, max(joinedAmount) mx
    from #tbl_name
    group by JoinedId
)
update #tbl_name
set joinedAmount = CTE.mx
from #tbl_name
join CTE on #tbl_name.JoinedId=CTE.JoinedId

select * from #tbl_name 

drop table #tbl_name
```